# How to tell Expo to install npm dependencies with --legacy-peerdeps option?

Tags: react-native, npm, build, expo, npm-install

I'm trying to build my Expo mobile app locally.

When Expo starts the [INSTALL_DEPENDENCIES] step, it performs `npm install`. But in my case, I'm aware of a legacy package I'm using which is causing some problems. So, this step is broken and the build is failing.

I want to configure Expo to perform `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` instead of `npm install`.

In my case, I have `rn-pdf-reader-js@4.1.1` with Expo SDK 46.

Is this option configurable?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After looking a little bit, I figured it out using:

Create `.npmrc` file in the project root directory with:

```
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

However, another option is to run `npm config set legacy-peer-deps true` in `eas-build-pre-install` [hook](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/how-tos/#eas-build-specific-npm-hooks).

In `package.json`, add the following to `scripts`:

```
 "eas-build-pre-install": "npm config set legacy-peer-deps true"
```

Comment: [PRE_INSTALL_HOOK] Script 'eas-build-pre-install' is present in package.json, running it...
[PRE_INSTALL_HOOK] 
Error: spawn yarn ENOENT
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:286:19)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:484:16)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
Build failed
Unknown error. See logs of the Pre-install hook build phase for more information.
npx exited with non-zero code: 1
    Error: build command failed.

This is the error I get